# Showing $-\int_0^1 {(1-x+\ln x)^2\ln x\over 3(1-x)^3} \, dx=\zeta(3)$

Tags: integration

> $$I=-\int_0^1 {(1-x+\ln x)^2\ln x \over 3(1-x)^3}\,dx=\zeta(3)\tag1$$

$${1\over 3(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(n+1)(n+2)x^n\over 6}\tag2$$

$$(1-x+\ln x)^2\ln x=\ln x-2x\ln x+x^2\ln x+2\ln^2 x-2x\ln^2 x+\ln^3 x\tag3$$
Sub $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ $\rightarrow (5)$

Let $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(n+1)(n+2)\over 6}\tag4$$

$$I=S\int_0^1 \left(x^n\ln x-2x^{n+1}\ln x+x^{n+2}\ln x+2x^n\ln^2 x -2x^{n+1} \ln x+x^n\ln^3 x\right)\tag5$$

$$\int_0^1 x^n\ln^m x \, dx={(-1)^m m!\over (n+1)^{m+1}}\tag6$$

Using $(6)$ to evaluate $(5)$ $\rightarrow (7)$

$$I=S\left[{-1\over (n+1)^2}+{2\over (n+2)^2}-{2\over (n+3)^2}+{4\over (n+1)^3}-{4\over (n+2)^3}-{6\over (n+1)^4}\right]\tag7$$

(7) seem to be wrong when I checked it with numerical calculation. Anyway this method it is tedious, but that is the only way I know how to solve this integral.

I check quite a numbers of time and can't spotted where I went wrong. Can you help please? Also show us another short approach to tackle integral I.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may compute first
$$ J(k) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\right)^k\,dx \tag{1}$$
for $k=1,2,3$ by integration by parts and get:
$$ J(1)=-\zeta(2),\qquad J(2)=2\zeta(2),\qquad J(3)=-3\zeta(2)-3\zeta(3) \tag{2}$$
then recognize that the original integral is just

> $$ -\frac{J(1) + 2\, J(2) + J(3)}{3}=\color{red}{\zeta(3)}\tag{3}$$

through the substitution $x=1-z$ and the binomial theorem.